# Flex remoteObject compression

Tags: java, apache-flex, compression, remoteobject, lcds

I have a Flex application which sends/receive a lot of data to/from the server. The bandwidth usage is high.
I'm using RemoteObject to send an XML(Document in Java). So I'd like to compress this XML and reduce the size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compress and decompress XML in Flex and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353752/compress-and-decompress-xml-in-flex-and-java)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RemoteObject with XML Data.  It negates all the benefits of using the XML Gateway.

Use HTTPService and enable GZIP compression on your web server.

For more info, see [the answers to this this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353752/compress-and-decompress-xml-in-flex-and-java/3353884#3353884)